# How to publish electron app to Windows store

Tags: electron, windows-store-apps, electron-builder

I have created electron app which I want to publish to Windows Store. I have read many blogs some are related compiling, signing certificate and publishing. I want to ask what are the steps I need to follow including compiling the application, signing code and uploading it to store.

Comment: build nsis windows app https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis

Comment: Thank You, but what after building about signing and publishing to store?

Comment: you can follow this process https://medium.com/@sangamrajpara/publishing-electron-app-to-windows-store-3cadeed26a32